# Adobe Animate (HTML5 Canvas) check timeline position of two movie clips and then display another movieclip if both movieclips are on frame 2

Tags: html, canvas, jquery-animate, adobe, easeljs

In Adobe Animate (HTML5 Canvas) I need to check if two buttons have been clicked on and advanced to the second frame and if both have then display a movieclip.

I am new to programming and not sure how to even begin.  I thought of using eventListner or an if/else statement. Not getting either to work.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try and answer the question to my knowledge, hopefully, it is simple enough to follow, but I'm sure there are probably better ways to write these functions.

buttonClick(evt) allows the buttons to be toggled on and off, assuming that frame 0 of the movieclips handles the off state of the buttons and frame 1 handles the on state.  A function is then called on every click to check the states of the buttons.

checkButtonStates() is a conditional statement that just checks the current frame of the buttons, and if both are at 1 the movieclip is displayed and played.

```js
const button1 = stage.children[0].button1_mc;
const button2 = stage.children[0].button2_mc;
const movieclip3 = stage.children[0].movieclip3_mc;

button1.addEventListener("click", buttonClick);
button2.addeventListener("click", buttonClick);

function buttonClick(evt) {
    button = evt.currentTarget;
    // check current frame of button and changes frame
    if (button.currentFrame == 0){
        button.gotoAndStop(1);
    } else {
        button.gotoAndStop(0);
    }
    checkButtonStates();
}

function checkButtonStates(){
    // if both buttons have been clicked hide buttons and play movie
    if (button1.currentFrame == 1 && button2.currentFrame == 1){
        showButtons(false);
        showAndPlayMovie(true);
    }
}

// buttons visible property set by passed parameter
function showButtons(bool){
    button1.visible = bool;
    button2.visible = bool;
}

// changes visible property of movie by passed parameter.  If movie is visible the movie is played.
function showAndPlayMovie(bool){
    movieclip3.visible = bool;
    if (movieclip3.visible == true){
        movieclip3.play();
    }
}
```